# UIColor from hex string representation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsstring, hex, uicolor

any snippet to get from:

```
NSString *_s = @"#000000";
```

to:

```
[UIColor blackColor];
```

any help is highly appreciated, just been messing around with an ugly code to do this :(

Answer (score 1):

A modified version - also takes an Alpha value

```
#define UIColorFromRGBA(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF000000) >> 24))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 blue:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8 ))/255.0 alpha:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) \
[UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0x0000FF))/255.0 \
alpha:1.0]
```

Use it like:

```
UIColorFromRGB(0x4c4c4c)
```

Comment: That's great for an integer constant, but not so useful with a string (such as from a file) which is what @dhomes is asking about.

Comment: Fulvio, MANY MANY THANKS! Jack, thanks for but quite, from string to UIColor, not rgbValue.  oh, only detail on code by Fulvio: line 11 i changed to:  hexColor = [hexColor substringFromIndex:1]; cString wasn't initialized nor is part of the method's signature

Comment: @dhomes Ahh yes, I've fixed my original answer with your code fix. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a category on `UIColor` that accomplishes this:

Create a new Objective-C category. In your header:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

@interface UIColor (Hex)

+ (UIColor*)colorFromHex:(NSString*)hex;

@end
```

And in your implementation:

```
@implementation UIColor (Hex)

+ (UIColor*)colorFromHex:(NSString *)hex
{
    unsigned result = 0;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hex];

    [scanner setScanLocation:0];
    [scanner scanHexInt:&result];

    return UIColorFromRGB(result);
}

@end
```

This assume your hex string is in the format `000000`, but you can adjust to to your needs to account for a # (change `[scanner setScanLocation:0]` to `[scanner setScanLocation:1]`).